# Button size change when typing text, how can I stop that?

Tags: android, xml, button, grid-layout

My problem is that the button size change when I type more text in the Button:

My GridLayout:

[image: click me]

The problem arises when I type more text in the Button:

[image: click me]

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:text="Buttonnnnnnnnnnn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1" />

    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Changing

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

does not work

I don't want that the Button size changed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a GridLayout to manage the width and height using weights, so you can set `0dp` on the Button sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `layout:height` and `layout:width` constant as some 'xdp'. Because, if you make it wrap content , it will automatically adjust according to the text size to wrap the whole text inside it.